# A natural numbered random value with probablility 0 for each number?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $M = [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ be the space of infinite sequences of reals between 0 and 1 with the product measure of the Lebesgue measure.

Define equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$ with $a\sim b$ if $a_i = b_i$ eventually, i.e there exists some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $a_n = b_n$. Let $[x]$ denote the equivalence class of a sequence $x$, and define a function $r: M/\sim \to M$ that assigns a representative to each equivalence class.

Consider the following process:

- Sample sequence $s$ from $M$.
- Compute $N$, the smallest integer where $s$ starts agreeing with its representative $r([s])$.

Formally, $N$ is a function $N: M\to \mathbb{N}$.

My questions are the following:

- Is $N$ measurable? My intuition is no.
- What is the distribution of $N$?
- Even if $N$ is not measurable, intuitively, any finite integer should be assigned probability $0$. This is because for a fixed $s$, there appears to be many more ways it could've started agreeing with its representative on the first digit than the zeroth, and many more ways it could start agreeing on the second than the first, etc. so that it should never begin agreeing on the $n$th digit for any finite $n$. Even if $N$ is not measurable, this is hard to wrap my head around. The process seems well defined to produce a natural number, but any natural number has probability $0$ of being produced.

Comment: "many more ways it could start agreeing on the second than the first"?  Are you saying $\mathfrak c^2 > \mathfrak c$?

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is not measurable, then one cannot reasonably assign
probability outcomes for $N$.
It feels weird that one cannot assign a probability to certain sets,
but this is why we have measurability in the first place:
We can only discuss probabilities for measurable sets.

> The process seems well defined to produce a natural number,

It depends what you mean with well defined here.
Note that the function $r$ is not given explicitly, we only know that such a function exists.
The existence of $r$ requires the axiom of choice here.
So there cannot be an explicit way to describe $N$, and one could argue that it is not
really well defined because its output depends on the choice for $r$.

I think that your intuition that $N$ is not measurable is correct.
Note that it is based on the (most likely non-measurable) function $r$.

Comment: Is there also a practical difficulty in  "sampling sequence $s$ from $M$" where the terms in the infinite tail are more important than those near the start for finding $r([s])$?